# Paypal Unsubscription

Tags: api, paypal, unsubscribe

Can I unsubscribe my user from Paypal recurring payments without leaving him my site. I want to know if there is some API call that I can make to unsubscribe my user.

Paypal provides a unsubscibe button , when user clicks on that , user is redirected to paypal site and then he can unsubscribe . I want to know if I can have some button , which when user clicks cancels his subscription . I do not want my user to be redirected to Paypal site .

Answer (score 0):

`ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus`

You can use this to :

Cancel – Only profiles in Active or Suspended state can be canceled.

Suspend – Only profiles in Active state can be suspended.

Reactivate – Only profiles in a suspended state can be reactivated.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus_API_Operation_NVP/

P.S ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus works only for I- Profiles